# Unable to debug SharePoint Code

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, sharepoint-2010

I cannot seem to debug any of my SharePoint code because of this issue. **SharePoint 2010** and **vs 2010** in **windows 7**. I have tried going to the help and doing some suggested commands and such but nothing seems to help.

Has any one encountered this? Know what to do?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to debug a local SharePoint or a remote SharePoint?

Comment: Local SharePoint. Im Doing Local Development. @SteveB

Comment: have you tried to attach debugger to IIS process using "attach process"